# WCF- redundancy in specifying service name and contract type?

Tags: c#, wcf

Say I have a service contract specified in IEmployService.cs as such:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IEmployeeService {
      /* ... */
    }
}
```

and an implementation file in EmployeeService.svc:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
   public class EmployeeService: IEmployeeService {
       /* implements IEmployeeService fully */    
   }
}
```

now, when I specify my endpoint in my Web.config file, I've seen everybody do this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.EmployeeService">
    <endpoint
      address="basic1"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="MyNamespace.IEmployeeService"
      ></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<!-- other tags -->
<system.serviceModel>
```

It seems like WCF aught to be able to infer what the contract type is without having to specify `contract="MyNamespace.IEmployeeService"`, since it already has a reference to EmployeeService (who implements the IEmployeeService interface that specifies the service contract). Is this contract attribute in my endpoint strictly necessary?  If so, I'd love to know why.

Comment: could this contract-attribute be necessary because EmployeeService might implement MULTIPLE contracts? I could see that being necessary then.

Answer (score 0):

It is at least partially because my class EmployeeService is not restricted to implementing a single service contracted interface.  Say I specify a new contract ISuperContract.cs:

```
namespace MultipleEndpointSample
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface ISuperService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void GetEmployeeName();
    }
}
```

then the contract-attribute in my Web.config: endpoint definition is very necessary, I now use it to differentiate WHICH sub-service of EmployeeService (which implements two services) this endpoint will cater to.